# Yii2 - Validate AccessControl over IP

Tags: yii2

I would like to restrict access to a controller to only one IP (or an IP list).

What is the right way to configure? 
(Example, I would like only IP `172.19.37.175` to have access to `index.php?r=painel/restrict`).

I tried this way:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::classname(),
            'only'  => ['index'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                    'ips' => ['172.19.37.175'],
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
            throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to access this page');
                    }                
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Your code .. seems correct  .. what's  your question  .. you have error? .. worng result?

Comment: When trying to access with my IP 172.19.37.175, it appears: You are not allowed to access this page

Comment: accessing index ?? index.php?r=index?

Comment: yes,the module address is: painel/restrict/index

Comment: how is called  the  controller  in your question?

Comment: RestrictController.php

Comment: then should be index.php?r=restrict/index

Comment: its "not Found"

Comment: It's a module, so I need to access it as "module / controller / view" = panel / restrict / index

Comment: its works ! i change to "'roles' => ['@']"

Comment: good work   .. well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
'roles' => ['?']
```

to

```
'roles' => ['@']
```